# Pandas; Python - VLookup

Tags: python, pandas

This is my first time posting a question, so take it easy on me if I don't know stack overflow norm of asking questions.

Attached is a snippet of what I am trying to accomplish on my side-project. I want to be able to compare a user input with a database `.xlsx` file that was imported by pandas.

I want to compare the user input with the database `column ['Component']`, if that component is there, it will grab its properties associated with that component.

```
comp_loc = r'C:\Users\ayubi\Documents\Python Files\Chemical_Database.xlsx'
data = pd.read_excel(comp_loc)

print(data)

LK = input('What is the Light Key?: ') #Answer should be Benzene in this case

if LK == data['Component'].any():
    Tcrit = data['TC, (K)']
    Pcrit = data['PC, (bar)']
    A = data['A']
    B = data['B']
    C = data['C']
    D = data['D']
else:
    print('False')
```

Results

```
   Component  TC, (K)  PC, (bar)      A      B      C      D
0  Benzene     562.2       48.9 -6.983  1.332 -2.629 -3.333
1   Toluene    591.8       41.0 -7.286  1.381 -2.834 -2.792

What is the Light Key?: Benzene
False
```

Please let me know if you have any questions.

I do appreciate your help!

Comment: I guess the vlookup command in excel is different in python? I tried What you have suggested, and now I get the following error. 
```

LK = input('What is the Light Key?: ') #Answer should be Benzene in this case

if data.loc[data['Component'].eq(LK)]:
    Tcrit = data['TC, (K)']
    Pcrit = data['PC, (bar)']
    A = data['A']
    B = data['B']
    C = data['C']
    D = data['D']
else:
    print('False')


The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by taking advantage of indices and using the `df.loc` accessor in pandas:

```py
# set index to Component column for convenience
data = data.set_index('Component')
LK = input('What is the Light Key?: ') #Answer should be Benzene in this case

# check if your lookup is in the index
if LK in data.index:
    # grab the row by the index using .loc
    row = data.loc[LK]
    # if the column name has spaces, you need to access as key
    Tcrit = row['TC, (K)']
    Pcrit = row['PC, (bar)']
    # if the column name doesn't have a space, you can access as attribute
    A = row.A
    B = row.B
    C = row.C
    D = row.D
else:
    print('False')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a great case for an Index. Set `'Component'` to the Index, and then you can use a very fast `loc` call to look up the data. Instead of the `if-else` use a `try-except` as a KeyError is going to tell you that the LK doesn't exist, without requiring the slower check of first checking whether it's in the index.

I also highly suggest you keep the values as a single Series, instead of floating around as 6 different varibales. It's simple to access each item by the Series index, i.e. Series['A'].

```
df = df.set_index('Component')

def grab_data(df, LK):
    try:
        return df.loc[LK]
    except KeyError:
        return False

grab_data(df, 'Benzene')
#TC, (K)     562.200
#PC, (bar)    48.900
#A            -6.983
#B             1.332
#C            -2.629
#D            -3.333
#Name: Benzene, dtype: float64

grab_data(df, 'foo')
#False
```

Comment: Thank you Sir. I do appreciate your help and suggestion into looking into Series.